# Why is my Javascript fizzbuzz code not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create a JS function that will print Fizz when a number divisible by 3 appears and Buzz if it is divisible by 5 and Fizzbuzz if both 5 and 3 but keeps printing "undefined" on chrome>sources>snippets. I have previously managed to run JS there but now it is just printing "undefined". Please help what is wrong with my code? Thank you in advance

This is my code:

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
  if (count % 3 === 0) {
    output.push("Fizz");
  }
  if (count % 5 === 0) {
    output.push("Buzz");
  }
  if (count % 15 === 0) {
    output.push("FizzBuzz");
  } else {
    output.push(count);
  }

  count++;

  console.log(output);
};
```

Comment: You defined the function but you never call it. Add `fizzBuzz()` at the end.

Comment: Also missing a loop.. and correct logic for the if’s.. see else-if, and work to pair if-else-if-else groups for clarity; for independent if statements, add a blank line to make such apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function using `fizzBuzz()`. You'd likely want to do this in a loop until it reaches a certain number.

In the example below, I use a `while` loop to call the function until `count` reaches 100. I've also moved the `console.log()` call to the end of the loop, as it doesn't make sense to log the entire array after each iteration.

Also, consider using `else if` statements so that `Fizz` or `Buzz` are only pushed if `FizzBuzz` has not been pushed. Otherwise, you may find that all three are pushed instead of just `FizzBuzz`.

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
  if (count % 15 === 0) {
    output.push("FizzBuzz");
  }
  else if (count % 3 === 0) {
    output.push("Fizz");
  }
  else if (count % 5 === 0) {
    output.push("Buzz");
  }
  else {
    output.push(count);
  }

  count++;
};

while(count < 100) {
    fizzBuzz();
}
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
var output = [];

function fizzBuzz(i) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        output.push("FizzBuzz");
      } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        output.push("Fizz");
      } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        output.push("Buzz");
      } else {
        output.push(i)
      }
      console.log(output)
};

fizzBuzz(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
  if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
    output.push("FizzBuzz");
  }
  else if (count % 3 === 0) {
    output.push("Fizz");
  }
  else if (count % 5 === 0) {
    output.push("Buzz");
  }
  else {
    output.push(count);
  }

  count++;
};

while(count < 100) {
    fizzBuzz();
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: code-only answers are discouraged. Especially a short explanation of the changed logic would be helpful.